# Upper approximation of $\mathrm{atanh}(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, approximation

Is there are nice upper approximation of $\mathrm{atanh(x)}$?
For example, $\ln(x)$ is nicely approximated by $x-1$ for $x$ around $1$.

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{atanh}(x)=\frac12\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$, so any upper bound on $\ln$ gives you an upper bound on $\operatorname{atanh}$.

Comment: $\ln x$ is not "nicely approximated" by $x-1$ for "small $x$." It is nicely approximated by $x-1$ for $x$ close to $1$...

Comment: Ok. I will add the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rahul said in the comment above we can write [inverse hyperbolic functions as logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms). With this approach we get for all $\left| x \right| < 1$:
$$\operatorname{artanh}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left( \frac{1 + x}{1 - x} \right).$$

No we can use logarithmic inequalities. We have that for all $x>0$:
$$1-\frac{1}{x} \leq \ln x \leq x-1.$$

Use of this we can get bounds for $\operatorname{artanh}$ for all $0<x<1$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) \leq \operatorname{artanh}(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}-1\right).$$

You can have more accurate bounds with [*Padé approximant*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant). For example you can get an upper bound with second order Padé approximant like this. We know that for all $x>0$:

$$\ln x \leq \frac{(x-1)(x+5)}{2+4x}.$$

Using this we get for $\operatorname{atanh}$ function for all $0<x<1$ the following.

$$\operatorname{artanh}(x) \leq \frac{x(2x-3)}{(x+3)(x-1)} = \psi_2(x).$$

I give you result using this method.

$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{artanh}(0.1) = 0.1003353477 & \leq 0.1003584228 = \psi_2(0.1), \\
\operatorname{artanh}(0.3) = 0.3095196042 & \leq 0.3116883116 = \psi_2(0.3), \\
\operatorname{artanh}(0.5) = 0.5493061443 & \leq 0.5714285715 = \psi_2(0.5), \\
\operatorname{artanh}(0.7) = 0.8673005277 & \leq 1.009009010\phantom{0} = \psi_2(0.7), \\
\operatorname{artanh}(0.9) = 1.472219490\phantom{0} & \leq 2.769230769\phantom{0} = \psi_2(0.9).
\end{align}
$

With this approach you can get also lower bounds and of course for more precise bounds you can use higher order Padé approximants. In this really good [paper](http://ajmaa.org/RGMIA/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf) you find hiher order Padé approximants for $\ln$, from them you can construct bounds for $\operatorname{artanh}$.

I have written more details about Padé approximants and approximation of the logarithm function in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/919287/153012). Feel free to read it.

Answer (score 1):

$$Atanh(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1+2 k}}{1+2 k}, |x|<1$$
And
$$Atanh(x) = -\frac{\pi \sqrt{-x^2}}{2 x}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{-1-2 k}}{1+2 k}, |x|>1$$

You can approximate it by using $$\sum_{k=0}^n$$ and decide what $n$ gives the level of approximation you need.

Comment: But this would give a lower approximation, right? I need an upper.

Comment: For very small $x$, $f(x)=x$ approximates it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \mathrm{atanh}(x) = \mathrm{asinh}(\sqrt{y})\qquad\text{, where } x ≥ 0\;,\;y=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$

If y is big, we can reduce it, with "half-angle" formula

$\displaystyle \mathrm{asinh}(\sqrt{y}) = 2\;\mathrm{asinh}
\left(\sqrt{\frac{y/2}{\sqrt{y+1}+1}} \right) $

**asinh has taylor series of alternating signs**, we can easily get both bounds.

$\displaystyle \mathrm{asinh}(\sqrt{y}) =
\sqrt{y}\;\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{1^2·y}{2·3}\right) \left[ 1 - \left(\frac{3^2·y}{4·5} \right)\left[ 1 - \left(\frac{5^2·y}{6·7}\right) \left[\,...\,
\right] \right]\right]\right]$

To make bounds even tighter, we flip "last" factor, $\displaystyle (1-ε) → \frac{1}{(1+ε)}$
Example, for upper bound of $\;\large \mathrm{atanh}(0.9)$

```
lua> x = 0.9
lua> y = x*x / (1-x*x)          --> 4.263, y too big
lua> y = y/2 / (sqrt(y+1)+1)    --> 0.647
lua> y = y/2 / (sqrt(y+1)+1)    --> 0.142
lua> y = y/2 / (sqrt(y+1)+1)    --> 0.034
lua> y = y/2 / (sqrt(y+1)+1)    --> 0.0085
lua> r = sqrt(y) * 2^4

lua> r
1.4742977995430115
lua> r * (1 - y/6 / (1 + 9/20*y))
1.4722194992970188
lua> r * (1 - y/6 * (1 - 9/20*y * (1 - 25/42*y / (1 + 49/72*y))))
1.472219489583329
lua> atanh(x)
1.4722194895832204
```