# Calculate $\lfloor \log _{2} \pi + \log _{\pi} 5 +\log_5 8 \rfloor=?$

Tags: logarithms

Calculate $$\lfloor \log _{2} \pi + \log _{\pi} 5 +\log_5 8 \rfloor=?$$

I suppose that:

$$\log_2 3 < \log _{2} \pi <\log_2 4 $$
But how can I approximate the $\log_2 3$?

Can somebody give an idea?

Comment: did you mean $\log_23<\log_2\pi<\log_24$?

Comment: Yes. I corrected

Comment: I would come up with $\lfloor\frac{\log (5)}{\log (\pi )}+\frac{\log (\pi )}{\log (2)}+\frac{\log (8)}{\log (5)}\rfloor=4$. But it seems to be too simple that makes me feeling reluctant providing it as an answer. How to approximate $\log_2(x)$ is explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706939/approximation-log-2x

Comment: As I see it, it's an approximation, I thought it was some other method without approximation. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if helpful: The product of those three $\log$s is exactly equal to $3$ since $\log_{a}(b) = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$.

Comment: You need to able to decide, for each term, whether it is greater than or less than $4/3$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Good point, and the maximum value of $x+y+z$ occurs when they are all equal, so $=\sqrt[3]{3}$, thus the maximum value of the expression is  $4.32$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Do you mean the other way around? AM-GM here tells us that $x + y + z \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{3}$. Since the three are not equal, the inequality is strict.

Comment: @MarkBen Here's a useful video to approximate $log_2(3):$ https://youtu.be/X6C5hGpWW5A

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes, sorry, that makes the question easier, the minimum value is $4.32$ now you just have to show it is $<5$.

Comment: I get that each term is $<5/3$

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Yes, that is true. But showing $\log_2(\pi) < 5/3$ by hand is a bit tricky since $\pi^3$ is actually quite close to $31 =2^5 - 1$. However, the other terms can be bounded better easily, which makes it easy to get away with showing $x < 2$. (See my answer for more details.)

Comment: You should accept an answer if it answers your question completely (and I think the current ones do) or ask for clarification. (Even your earlier questions don't have any accepted answer.)

Comment: @devam_04 Thanks.

Comment: All the answers helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}$Let $a = \log_{2}(\pi)$, $b = \log_{\pi}(5)$, and $c = \log_{5}(8)$.

Then, we have $abc = \log_{2}(8) = 3$.
Thus, by the AM-GM inequality, we have $$a + b + c \geqslant 3 \sqrt[3]{3} \geqslant 4.$$
(The second inequality follows by showing that $\sqrt[3]{3} \geqslant \frac{4}{3}$. To check that, simply note that $3^4 > 4^3$ and then take cube roots and rearrange.)

Thus, $\fl{a + b + c} \geqslant 4$. To show that it is equal to $4$, it suffices to show that $$a + b + c < 5.$$

**Claim 1.** $a < 2$.
*Proof.* $\log_{2}(\pi) < \log_{2}(4) = 2$. $\square$

**Claim 2.** $b < \frac{5}{3}$.
*Proof.* Note that $$\log_{\pi}(5) < \frac{5}{3} \iff 5^3 < \pi^5.$$
But the second statement is clearly true since
$$5^3 = 125 < 243 = 3^5 < \pi^5. \qquad \square$$

**Claim 3.** $c < \frac{4}{3}$.
*Proof.* As before, this reduces to showing that $$8^3 < 5^4,$$ which is easily checked. $\square$

Thus, we have $$a + b + c < 2 + \frac{5}{3} + \frac{4}{3} = 5,$$
as desired.

Comment: Nice. Actually the first is $<5/3$, but it is better to do as you have done and take the difference from the last.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Agreed, but it's easier to show that it is $<2$ and let $c$ compensate. (Indeed, the only estimate I use throughout is that $3 < \pi < 4$. To get $\log_{2}(\pi) < 5/3$, one would need something like $\pi < 3.15$.)

Comment: Isnt that what I just said :-)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus No, Aryaman Maithani said more and in more detail.

Comment: I somehow didn't see your answer. I could see it only after I finished uploading my answer. My answer looks similar to yours, should I delete mine?

Comment: @Koro: I think it is fine. We technically use different bounds.

Comment: How come nobody is up voting the original question ?

Answer (score 2):

By AM >GM,

$$\log_2\pi+\log_\pi5+\log_58\ge 3(3)^\frac 13\approx 4.33 \tag 1$$

Note that $$\log_2\pi+\log_\pi5+\log_58\lt \log_22^2+\log_\pi5+\log_{2^2}2^3=2+\frac 32+\log_\pi5=3.5+\log_\pi5\tag2$$

$5^2\lt \pi^3$ so $\log_\pi5^2\lt 3\implies \log_\pi5\lt \frac 32\tag 3$

Using $(3)$ in $(2)$ to get:
$$\log_2\pi+\log_\pi5+\log_58\lt 3.5+1.5=5\tag 4$$

By $(1)$ and $(4)$,  $$\lfloor\log_2\pi+\log_\pi5+\log_58\rfloor=4$$