# Problem with custom made natural log and power functions

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponentiation

I have made these two functions with the help of posts on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com).

For `ln` I'm using information gathered from [Calculate Logarithms by Hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61279/calculate-logarithms-by-hand) and for calculating powers I'm using [How to Calculate a Decimal Power of a Number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/how-to-calculate-a-decimal-power-of-a-number)

The functions I wrote seem to be working fine with smaller numbers like
    3<sup>2</sup>, which result in `9.00003048002563640458932185659665779695115234`.

3<sup>20</sup> results in `3486902488.6640151119143428706046321880279236576908532` but when I compare this result with the built in language function I'm using the result is `3486784401` ; the difference between the integers is `118087`.

It seems there's a limit to the methods I'm using but could I get this confirmed please and thanks? Or would there exist methods I could use to calculate more accurate<sup>*</sup> answers?

Psuedo code for my power function:

Comments used: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21386/288031, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180655/288031

```
function pow (a,b)
    stringify a and b;

    if b is 1 return a;
    else if b is 0 return 1;

    m => is the product of b and the custom natural log function of a;
    m is stringified;

    n => is the parsed integer value of m, then stringified;
    o => is the difference of m and n, which should result in just the decimal value;

    p => 1; // will be the stored product

    loop
        use i for our index (i starts at zero)
        loop while i is less than n

        p => is the product of p and euler's number

        i => add i and 1

    // the built-in euler's number I'm referring to is just the
    // built-in Math.exp(o) function which just avoids using 
    // built-in Math.pow( Math.E, o )
    return the product of p and built-in euler's number raised to the power of o
```

Pseudo code for my natural log function:

Using comment https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61283/288031

```
function ln (z)
    b => stores (z - 1) divided by (z + 1); // value doesn't change in the loop
    exp_counter => 1;
    current => 0;
    previous => -1;
    n => 0;

    c => 1;

    loop while current and previous do not equal // convergence
        previous => current;

        d => is the sum of 1 and (2 * n);
        a => is 1 / d;

        // power calculator without power function
        loop while exp_counter is less than d
            c => c * b;
            exp_counter => 1 + exp_counter;
        end loop

        current => current + (a * c);
        n => n + 1
    end loop

    return current * 2;
```

<sup>*</sup>Accuracy: I have a number of "items" (63) and I wanted to calculate the total combinations I could use these items; using binary bits to represent each 63 items I am using 2<sup>63</sup> for the answer. I used my custom functions to calculate the answer and compared with http://wolframalpha.com. My answer from the custom functions wont satisfy what I need in order to accurately represent the total combinations of the items. (answer I generated from 2<sup>63</sup> = `9232375753198674821.914432211635780578399921666955505030143435683`)

Comment: Define "accurate". Also, define what method you're using specifically. There are several different ones on the pages you linked to.

Comment: Isn't there a different place for math that involves coding?  +1 for trying  :)

Comment: :D I almost considered `CodeReview` -- literally copied and pasted what I wrote there and switched to `Math`